# Vertical center span inside floated div

Tags: html, css

I have a list of divs like a menu and I want to center the spans inside them. It works if they are not floated, but once I float them, it won't center the spans anymore. Any idea why and how to solve this?

```css
#panel {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 80px;
  
}
span {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel"><span>Some caption  </span>
</div>
<div id="panel"><span>Some caption </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rj1njhj/)**

CSS:

```
#panel {
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* tall height for emphasis */
}
span {
    background-color: green;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you dont need full height, you can use like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rj1njhj/1/)**

CSS:

```
#panel {
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* tall height for emphasis */
}
span {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#panel {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 80px;
  /* tall height for emphasis */
}
span {
  float:left;
  margin-top:13%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel"><span>Some caption  </span>
</div>
<div id="panel"><span>Some caption </span>
</div>
```